# Enumerations? Can anybody explain it. thanks

Tags: combinatorics

How many different 5-letter “words” (sequences) are there with no repeated
letters formed from the 26-letter alphabet

Comment: I'm gonna start putting a penny into a jar every time someone asks this, if anyone has a problem with this he will be able to find me in my private island.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** How many options are there for the first letter? After you used one letter how many for the second?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Consider $5$ slots to fill in the letters.

In the first box, there are $26$ options.

In the second box, there are $26-1$ options, as we cannot repeat the previous letter.

Do similar stuff for third, fourth and fifth box.

Multiply them up.

Answer (score 0):

Its P(26,5).

= $\frac{26!}{21!}$

= $\frac{26 \times 25 \times 24 \times 23 \times 22 \times 21!}{21!}$

So you have $26 \times 25 \times 24 \times 23 \times 22$ as a answer.

> Edit -

You are picking first letter you have 26 options. After picking first letter you have 25 option to pick second letter. So on for picking 5 letters.

Then you have $26 \times 25 \times 24 \times 23 \times 22$ as a answer.